# jquery-plugin-validation error message location

Tags: php, jquery, css, validation

I'm try to validate form using [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

my from code: [`source code`](http://jsfiddle.net/dduleep/Gzrub/4/)

every validation error message view only in front of the first field.
How to view error message correct location (near the field)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your inputs have the same `id` attribute. Make them unique for each input.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTYP2/).